# Replacing value of atribut with count condition requirement

Tags: postgresql

I have a data with is shown below :

```
count | type of vegetation

1     | Semak Belukar, Pepohonan

2     | Pakis, Sawit, Senduduk 

1     | Pakis, Sawit, Ilalang, Akasia

49    | Sawit

15    | Pakis, Karet

17    | Semak Belukar
```

I'd like to replace the value of type of vegetation which has value of count that is less than 15 into 'Others'. Example below :

```
count | type of vegetation 

1     | Others

2     | Others

1     | Others

49    | Sawit

15    | Pakis, Karet

17    | Semak Belukar
```

I use postgres SQL and haven't found the solution yet.
Any help is apreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this to view the expected result.

```
select count, 
CASE WHEN count < 15 THEN 'Others' 
ELSE type_of_vegetation 
END as type_of_vegetation
FROM yourtable;
```

To update your table as required, use this.

```
update yourtable SET type_of_vegetation = (
CASE WHEN count < 15 THEN 'Others' 
    ELSE type_of_vegetation 
 END );
```

[**DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/52652/1)

Comment: sorry, i'd like to update table above, but haven't found the solution yet @Kaushik Nayak.